# sql DISTINCT with COALESCE

Tags: sql, coalesce

I am working with two tables in a database where the first table (T1) consist of measurements from a device and the other table (T2) has the information on each individual device.

In T2 there is a column called `METADATA1` which could be a description, an empty string or null.

I would like to write a query that gets all the distinct devices that have measurements in T1 and their METADATA1. I want to replace the empty/null metadata with deviceid. Here is what I have

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.DEVICEID), 
       COALESCE(NULLIF(t2.METADATA1,''), t1.DEVICEID) AS METADATA1 
FROM T1 t1 LEFT JOIN T2 t2 ON t1.DEVICEID = t2.DEVICEID 
ORDER BY t1.DEVICEID ASC
```

This returns zero rows and does not work. If I replace the COALESCE with `COALESCE(NULLIF(t2.METADATA1,''), '0')` then I get the correct number of rows.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be returning rows, assuming `t1` has rows.  I would express it using `GROUP BY` rather than `SELECT DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT t1.DEVICEID,
       COALESCE(NULLIF(MAX(t2.METADATA1), ''), t1.DEVICEID) AS METADATA1 
FROM T1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     T2 t2
     ON t1.DEVICEID = t2.DEVICEID 
GROUP BY t1.DEVICEID
ORDER BY t1.DEVICEID ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you but this only produces two records where as the one I use gives me 49. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ashkan . . . Without seeing your data, that is rather hard to speculate on.

Comment: Could you specify why do you prefer group by to distinct?

Comment: @Ashkan . . . Because I can use aggregation functions.